# Issues installing Cent OS 7 + Zen 3 5800x

Tags: centos, centos7, installation

Trying to install CentOS 7 on local DEV server.

Server specs:

```
CPU: Ryzen 7 5800x

Motherboard: ASRock B550M STEEL LEGEND AM4

RAM:  Corsair 32GB RAM

Hard Drive: 2x 500GB Corsair NVME

LAN: Intel Gigabit CT PCI-E Network Adapter EXPI9301CTBLK
```

I'm getting an error during the install:

[image]

I'm re-downloading Cent OS 7 Everything ISO instead, but not sure where to even start to fix this issue.

Hardware is definitely non standard / mainstream so I assume the fault is with the hardware drivers.

Any ideas what this error means?

UPDATE:

I have tried multiple apps to burn ISO:

- Rufus
- Win32DiskImager

I tried multiple ISOs (from http://centos.mirror.rafal.ca/7.9.2009/isos/x86_64/):

- CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-2009.iso
- CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-2009.iso

Same result.

UPDATE 2:

I also tried adding:

```
noacpi
nolapic
noapic
```

Same result.

Comment: You might want to read that rather old but I believe still accurate thread: https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=76489. Try your luck with an other distro. Ryzen 5000 and up CPUs are not supported.

Comment: @Zeitounator please post it as answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [a centos forum thread](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=76489), it seems that AMD Ryzen 5000 series and up CPUs are not and will never be supported by centos 7.

As this is the last point release for centos, you will have to try your luck with an other linux distribution on your recent machine.

Note that according to this thread, the centos 8 development release does not support your CPU either (but I actually did not try myself).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I moved on to CentOS 9 Stream - so far its getting installed no issues (besides the awful partitioning hard drives interface).